# store in a @var a table's name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Tags: sql, mysql

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%smi%';
+--------------+
| TABLE_NAME   | 
+--------------+ 
| smiley_files | 
| smileys      |
| smiley_files |
etc.
But:
mysql> SELECT @name:=(SELECT(TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME ='smileys'));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual etc.
```

How can I capture a table's name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and store in a @var (or into another table)?

Comment: user define variable can store only one value, so what do you need it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user define variables can only store one value so you would need somting like this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME) INTO @ltable 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME ='smileys';
```

As Table you would use

```
  CREATE TABLE MY_table as
SELECT TABLE_NAME  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME ='smileys';
```